# Where to save classes of the web-application

Tags: asp.net

I have to create a small asp.net-application. The last such web-application I have built was a while ago. At this time, I have saved my classes in the `App_Code`-folder.

During setting up the web-solution in VS2010, I have seen that VS does no more propose to create the `app_code` directory (right click on the project, Add asp.net-folder). Is the `App_Code` folder no more the prefered location to save classes  of the web-application and where is the new place to store them?

**Update**

Thanks to Oded I have received the answer to my question.

If one has the same question as I had, probably he is also not aware (as I was), that there are two different types of projects with their own menu-points in VS: **Web-Application** and **Web-Site**. The organisation of these two types is different. For a web-application, the `app_code`-folder is not proposed in the asp.net-folder-menu . Maybe this information helps someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the preferred place, but VS 2010 just doesn't automatically create it for you any more.

As you can see from the documentation of [`app_code`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t990ks23.aspx) for .NET 4.0, it is still the best place for shared code.

> In a Web site project, you can store source code in the App_Code folder, and it will be automatically compiled at run time. The resulting assembly is accessible to any other code in the Web application.